# Cannot access java.util.function.Predicate

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-codegen

I use swagger to generate code for spring server and try to run with intelliJ. However I got the following error message. Any help is appreciated.

```
java: cannot access java.util.function.Predicate
  class file for java.util.function.Predicate not found
```

on the line

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("io.swagger.api"))
```

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably using java version lower then java 8.
Please verify in your POM file:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

And also in the ide you are using java 8 or above.

Comment: This is my java version <java.version>1.7</java.version>. After changing it to 1.8. It works perfectly fine now.